# Python: How to check characters occurrence in string in one line

Tags: python

A string can be with both single `'_'` and double `'__'` underscore characters at the end. 
Checking it with :

`if myString[-1]=='_': pass`

works only for a single character. How to achieve the same using one line?

`(only if last character(s)=='_' or '__').`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python version > 2.5,

You can use [`endswith` with a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)

```
underscores = ('_', '__')
if myString.endswith(underscores): pass
```

Demo

```
>>> underscores = ('_', '__')
>>> xx = "text__"
>>> xxx = "text_"
>>> xx.endswith(underscores)
True
>>> xxx.endswith(underscores)
True
>>>
```

Comment: You can always put .endswith(['_', '__']): pass I like this solution. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can do that as:

```
if myString[-2:]=='__' or myString[-1] == '_':
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cant make assumptions about the string length, a better way to check is

```
if len(myString)-len(myString.rstrip('_')) in (1,2):
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
>>> re.match(".*[^_]__?$","test_")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='test_'>

>>> re.match(".*[^_]__?$","test__")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='test__'>

>>> re.match(".*[^_]__?$","test___")
None
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
MyString0 = 'Hello'
MyString1 = 'Hello_'
MyString2 = 'Hello__'
MyString3 = 'Hello___'

f = lambda x : x.endswith(('_', '__')) and not x.endswith(('___'))

print f(MyString0) # --> False
print f(MyString1) # --> True
print f(MyString2) # --> True
print f(MyString3) # --> False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. Here is how I ended up using it:

```
myString='asdfasdf.__'
invalid=['!','"','#','$','%','&','\\','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/'
                ,':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[',"'",']','^','`','{','|','}','~',' ','_']

while myString and myString[-1] in invalid:
    myString=myString.rstrip( invalid[ invalid.index(myString[-1]) ] )
```